# How to merge/join Spark/Scala RDD to List so each value in RDD gets a new row with each List item

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, rdd

Lets say I have a List[String] and I want to merge it with a RDD Object so that each object in the RDD gets each value in the List added to it:

```
List[String] myBands = ["Band1","Band2"];
```

Table: BandMembers
|name   | instrument |
| ----- | ---------- |
| slash | guitar     |
| axl   | vocals     |

```
case class BandMembers ( name:String, instrument:String );
var myRDD = BandMembersTable.map(a => new BandMembers(a.name, a.instrument));  
//join the myRDD to myBands
// how do I do this?
//var result = myRdd.join/merge/union(myBands);
```

Desired result:
|name   | instrument | band |
| ----- | ---------- |------|
| slash | guitar     | band1|
| slash | guitar     | band2|
| axl   | vocals     | band1|
| axl   | vocals     | band2|

I'm not quite sure how to go about this in the best way for Spark/Scala.  I know I can convert to DF and then use spark sql to do the joins, but there has to be a better way with the RDD and List, or so I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style is a bit off here, but assuming you really need RDD's instead of Dataset

So with RDD:

```scala
case class BandMembers ( name:String, instrument:String )
val myRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(BandMembersTable.map(a => new BandMembers(a.name, a.instrument)))
val myBands = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq("Band1","Band2"))
val res = myRDD.cartesian(myBands).map { case (a,b) => Row(a.name, a.instrument, b) }
```

With Dataset:

```scala
case class BandMembers ( name:String, instrument:String )
val myRDD = BandMembersTable.map(a => new BandMembers(a.name, a.instrument)).toDS
val myBands = Seq("Band1","Band2").toDS
val res = myRDD.crossJoin(myBands)
```

Input data:

```scala
val BandMembersTable = Seq(BandMembers("a", "b"), BandMembers("c", "d"))
val myBands = Seq("Band1","Band2")
```

Output with Dataset:

```scala
+----+----------+-----+
|name|instrument|value|
+----+----------+-----+
|a   |b         |Band1|
|a   |b         |Band2|
|c   |d         |Band1|
|c   |d         |Band2|
+----+----------+-----+
```

Println with RDDs (these are Rows)

```scala
[a,b,Band1]
[c,d,Band2]
[c,d,Band1]
[a,b,Band2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using RDD zip for this.. From official docs

RDD<scala.Tuple2<T,U>>  zip(RDD other, scala.reflect.ClassTag evidence$11)
Zips this RDD with another one, returning key-value pairs with the first element in each RDD, second element in each RDD,